# Estimate the threohold of reject region by Bootstrap

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, bootstrap, validity

I am studying the Bootstrap method and encountered a question about how to estimate the reject region. Suppose we have observed a sample $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$, I aim to investigate the linear correlation of the pairwise sequence $X_i$ and $Y_i$ without any infomation about the population.

To be specific, I have to perform the hypothesis test with null hypothesis $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The reject region is $W = \{(X, Y) \big| |\rho(X, Y)| > t\}$ where $\rho(X, Y)$ is the Pearson correlation coefficient. However, we don't know the value of the threshold $t$ for the significance level $\alpha = 0.05$ since the population is unkown. Thus I want to estimate $t$ by Bootstrap with the observed sample $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$.

The intuition comes from that Bootstrap is to estimate the distribtion of some parameters by leveraging resampling and the empirical distrbution. I try to get the empirical distribution by resampling $\{(X_i, Y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$.

I come up with a method as follows.

> 1. Resample for $m$ iterations, calculate the Pearson coefficient for each iteration and denote by $\rho_1, ... \rho_m$.
> 2. Determine the threshold $t$ by the 95% quantiles of $\rho_1, ..., \rho_m$.
> 3. Do hypothesis test with the determined $t$.

So does the procedure make sense? And I tried to check the validity of the method.

Comment: What is you hypothesis? What it the null value you assume regarding the Pearson coefficient?

Comment: @Kozolovska, The null hypothesis is $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The corresponding reject region is $\{(X, Y) \big| |\rho(X, Y)|  > t \}$. Since I want to control the type 1 error to $\alpha=0.05$, I would like to find such a $t$ by Bootstrap based on the observed sample $(X_i, Y_i)$. But I'm not able to claim the procedure I come up with is valid.